# How can I assign the 'rows' variable to 'config'?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, callback

Everytime I tried to extract 'rows' from the function, it returned 'undefined'

I tried doing something with the callback functions (as in the provided code below) but it also doesn't work.

```
const sqlite = require('sqlite3');

let db = new sqlite.Database('./db/db.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
});
function readDB(callback) {
   let sqlQuery = `SELECT DISTINCT gid gid, id id, lang lang, nsfw nsfw FROM servers WHERE gid = ${message.guild.id}`;
db.all(sqlQuery, [], (err, rows) => {
if (err) callback(err, null);
        callback(null, rows);
  });
}
   let config = readDB((err, rows) => { if (err) { console.log(err); return; } else { return rows } });
```

I would like to access the 'rows' variable from the 'config' variable to use it later in further code (for example: console.log(config.prefix) etc.).

Comment: it would be helpful to specify which sql library you're using to connect to sqlite. could you include the import/require statements in this snippet?

Comment: I've already added.

Comment: have you checked your SQL doesn't have an error or return 0 rows? Could you use else on `callback(null, rows);` so it is not always called?